# How to determine who a confused character attacks when there are multiple adjacent creatures

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I'm DMing and a couple of my party members have been affected by [confusion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/confusion.htm), and may end up having to attack the nearest creature. If there's one of them with both an enemy and an ally adjacent, how should we determine who they attack?

Do they get to choose? Or should I randomly determine which one gets attacked. If I determine randomly, should each attack be random, or will they go all in on whoever they randomly decide to attack.

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62762/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, that one kept coming up when I was looking for a ruling. I'm kinda surprised no-one mentioned the case of multiple nearest creatures

Answer (score 9):

The rules are silent on how exactly a [confused](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_confused&alpha=C) creature attacks multiple creatures equally close. This DM has always rolled dice to determine randomly which creature's attacked if multiple creatures are equidistant from the confused creature. Further, as a confused creature's actions are only determined once at the turn's beginning, this DM has always had the confused creature just go all in against whichever creature was randomly attacked rather than switching between equally close targets between attacks.

However, this player can imagine a DM opting to do things differently—especially having the creature switch foes between attacks, which I'd heretofore never considered—and wouldn't complain were the DM to excercise that option.

Comment: We have always simply assigned numbers to all nearby foes, and if multiple foes that the confused individual with multiple attacks can reach exist, roll to see which foes are struck out at for each attack. This is in both of my currently active groups, and in most of my previous groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

My method for confused characters, and even normal attack decisions for random brutes, is to have each viable target roll a die.  I'll ask for the lowest, the highest, or the closest to a die I roll behind the screen.  Any viable NPCs I roll for as well.